# How to generate right route in twig with dynamic sub-domain?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant APP based on sub-domain that's working properly but I have an issue with generated link in Twig templates.

All the generated link are on the default sub-domain and not the current one

## routes.yaml

```
app_customer:  
  resource: '../src/Controller/Customer/'  
  host: "{subdomain}.domain.com"  
  defaults:  
    subdomain: tenant1  
  requirements:  
    subdomain: tenant1|tenant2
```

## SecurityController.php

```
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ]);
    }
}
```

## login.html.twig

```
<form action="{{ path('app_login') }}" method="post">...</form>
```

will always generate `https://tenant1.domain.com/login` however the current url is `tenant2.domain.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is always generating `https://tenant1.domain.com/login` because you have "tenant1" set as the default value for `subdomain` and you do not pass a different value when you call `path()`

Try this :

```
{% set currsubdomain = app.request.getHttpHost()|split('.')|first %}

<form action="{{ path('app_login', {subdomain: currsubdomain }) }}" method="post">...</form>
```

Or maybe just pass the whole host:

```
<form action="{{ path('app_login', {host: app.request.getHttpHost}) }}" method="post">...</form>
```

Comment: Thank's you !
Your first purpose works perfectly with a small modification, it need to be generated with url() to be right.
<form action="{{ url('app_login', {subdomain: currsubdomain }) }}" method="post">...</form>

It seem that when you use dynamic subdomain, a default subdomain is mandatory but if anyone have another solution I'm open. 

This solution is working but need to be apply on any link.